# Infinite expression encountered in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

The code is

```
Clear["Global`*"]

\[Alpha] = 110.; \[Beta] = 55.; \[Delta] = 1; \[Mu]1 = 18.; \[Mu]2 = \
42.; \[Mu] = \[Mu]2/\[Mu]1;
deltap = .1;
w[\[Lambda]_, \[Xi]_] :=
      (-((\[Mu]1*\[Alpha])/2) Log[1 - (\[Lambda]^(-4) + 2*\[Lambda]^2 - 3)/\[Alpha]] - (\[Mu]2*\[Beta])/2 Log[1 - (\[Lambda]^-4*\[Xi]^4 + 2 \[Lambda]^2*\[Xi]^-2 -3)/\[Beta]])/\[Mu]1
dw[\[Lambda]_, \[Xi]_] := 
      D[w[\[Lambda], \[Xi]], \[Lambda]]
\[Xi]1[\[Lambda]_, \[Xi]_,x_] := 
      (1 + (\[Lambda]^3 - 1) (x^3 - 1)^-1 (\[Xi]^3 - 1))^(1/3)
f[\[Lambda]_, \[Xi]_, x_] := 
      dw[\[Lambda], \[Xi]1[\[Lambda], \[Xi], x]]/(1 - \[Lambda]^3)
sup[x_] := ((\[Delta] + x^3)/(1 + \[Delta]))^(1/3)
xlist = Range[0.4, 5.3, 0.01];
plist = Table[
   NIntegrate[f[\[Lambda], 1, x], {\[Lambda], x, sup[x]}], {x, 
    xlist}];
```

when evalueted, the warning is given

```
(*"Infinite expression 1/0. encountered"*)
```

Then, I examined the function `f[\[Lambda]_, \[Xi]_, x_]` and found it is not simplifed before `NIntegrate`.

Next, I define a new function `fs[\[Lambda]_, \[Xi]_Real, x_]` for the simplification before `NIntegrate` and codes are

```
Clear["Global`*"]

\[Alpha] = 110.; \[Beta] = 55.; \[Delta] = 1; \[Mu]1 = 18.; \[Mu]2 = \
42.; \[Mu] = \[Mu]2/\[Mu]1;
deltap = .1;
w[\[Lambda]_, \[Xi]_] := (-((\[Mu]1*\[Alpha])/2) Log[
      1 - (\[Lambda]^(-4) + 2*\[Lambda]^2 - 
          3)/\[Alpha]] - (\[Mu]2*\[Beta])/2 Log[
      1 - (\[Lambda]^-4*\[Xi]^4 + 2 \[Lambda]^2*\[Xi]^-2 - 
          3)/\[Beta]])/\[Mu]1
dw[\[Lambda]_, \[Xi]_] := D[w[\[Lambda], \[Xi]], \[Lambda]]
\[Xi]1[\[Lambda]_, \[Xi]_, 
  x_] := (1 + (\[Lambda]^3 - 1) (x^3 - 1)^-1 (\[Xi]^3 - 1))^(1/3)
f[\[Lambda]_, \[Xi]_, x_] := 
 dw[\[Lambda], \[Xi]1[\[Lambda], \[Xi], x]]/(1 - \[Lambda]^3)
sup[x_] := ((\[Delta] + x^3)/(1 + \[Delta]))^(1/3)
xlist = Range[0.4, 5.3, 0.01];
fs[\[Lambda]_, \[Xi]_Real, x_] := 
 f[\[Lambda], \[Xi], x] // FullSimplify;(*elimimate Power 1/0*)
plist = Table[
  NIntegrate[fs[\[Lambda], 1, x], {\[Lambda], x, sup[x]}], {x, 
   xlist}];
```

but failed again with warnings

```
(*"The integrand fs[\[Lambda],1,0.4] has evaluated to non-numerical \
values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries \
{{0.4,0.810284}}"*)
```

Any suggestions will be much appriciated!

Comment: It looks $f(\lambda, \xi, x)$ is not well-defined for $\lambda$ = 1.  The first approach seems to work for `xlist = Cases[Range[0.4, 5.3, 0.01], Except[1.0]]`.

Comment: In the second approach, instead of defining `fs` before `plist`, try this:  `plist = Table[fs = f[\[Lambda], 1, x]; 
  NIntegrate[fs, {\[Lambda], x, sup[x]}],
  {x, xlist}]`

Comment: @LouisB That's a way to obtain the result. But, is it possible to elimanite the singularity in  `NIntegrate` by some simplification ?

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary to eliminate the singularity. If you know the singularity, for example case `\[Xi]==1->\[Lambda]=1` just define

```
int[x_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[f[\[Lambda], 1, x], {\[Lambda], x, sup[x]},Exclusions -> {1}]

Plot[int[x], {x, .4, 5.3}, AxesLabel -> {x, "int[x]"}]
```

[image]

**addendum**

`Factor` removes the singularity

```
 Factor[f[\[Lambda], 1, x] // Rationalize]
 (*(110 (1 + \[Lambda]) (1 - \[Lambda] + \[Lambda]^2) (13 -1139 \[Lambda]^4 + 26 \[Lambda]^6))/(3 \[Lambda] (1 -113 \[Lambda]^4 + 2 \[Lambda]^6) (1 - 58 \[Lambda]^4 +2 \[Lambda]^6))*)
```

Just one hint: Try to define your parameters symbolical ( `\[Alpha] = 110 ;` instead of `\[Alpha] = 110.;`if you intend to do symbolical  transformations!

Comment: Yeah, it solves the problem here. I wonder if there are some funtions in MMA that can  change  priorities of the calculation. Just like the problem presented, first 'Simplication', then NIntegrate. That's a problem confusing me for a long time!

Comment: You might change the priorities applying the functions step by step. Sometimes the option `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0` inside `NIntegrate` is helpful.

Comment: For funtion `Plot`, no warnings are given. However, when function `Table` is applied, the same warning appears for the method you suggested.`int[x_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[f[\[Lambda], 1, x], {\[Lambda], x, sup[x]},Exclusions -> {1}]

Table[int[x], {x, xlist}];`

Comment: And are there some approaches to firstly reduce the fator `1-\[Lambda]`?